# Strange behavior of tensorflow when dividing by 0 in tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

So I do not know if is a bug or the problem is in my code, but I am trying to understand what is happening. 
when I run the model and got to estimate the accuracy using Mean Relative Error. I know in my validation data I have 0s so I was expecting to get some error or some inf. However this is not the case.
This is my code:

```
X_test_norm = preprocessing.scale(X_test)
predictions = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_test_norm})
prediction = tf.convert_to_tensor(predictions)
expectation = tf.cast(Y_test, tf.float32)

MANUAL_MRE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs((Y_test - tf.transpose(predictions)) / Y_test))
MAE_op, MAE = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(expectation, prediction)
MRE_op, MRE = tf.metrics.mean_relative_error(expectation, prediction, expectation)
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

print("MANUAL_MRE: %4f" % sess.run(MANUAL_MRE))
print("MRE: %4f" % sess.run(MRE))
print("MAE: %4f" % sess.run(MAE))
```

This is the output:

```
MANUAL_MRE:  inf

MRE: 1.603528

MAE: 76.489990
```

When I run it on a data that has values bigger than 0, my `MANUAL_MRE` and MRE values are the same like it should be. I checked the documentation of TF and the first case does not make sense.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong or I just found a bug/ new feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening because the MRE is a mean value of each Mean Relative Errors, therefore I believe that the `tf.metrics.mean_relative_error` is just adding like the value completely did not matched with the prediction. I believe thats why when I calculate MRE with dataset that I know it hase negtive values as labels gives me such a high MRE values.

You can maybe understand better why I think so from the code bellow:

```
MANUAL_MRE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs((Y_test + 100) - (tf.transpose(predictions) + 100)) / (Y_test + 100))
MANUAL_TF_MRE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.divide(tf.abs(Y_test - tf.transpose(predictions)), Y_test))
MRE_op, MRE = tf.metrics.mean_relative_error(exp, predTF, exp)
tf.initialize_local_variables().run()

print("MANUAL_TF_MRE: %4f" % sess.run(MANUAL_TF_MRE))
print("MANUAL_MRE: %4f" % sess.run(MANUAL_MRE))
print("MRE: %4f" % sess.run(MRE))

MANUAL_TF_MRE:  inf
MANUAL_MRE: 0.084013
MRE: 4.255613
```